# Do warlocks regain all their spell slots on a short rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, spell-slots, rests

I keep seeing all over the internet that warlocks get all their warlock spell slots back on a short rest. However, none of the page references seem to point to the correct spot.

Do you know if this is true or not and what page it can be found on?

Comment: Do you own the Players Handbook?  If not, have [you looked at the WoTC web site and checked out the SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf)?  The info is in both of those sources under the Warlock class.  If you aren't sure why you got all of those down votes, [this may clear it up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5270/22566).

Answer (score 36):

### Yes, warlock spell slots return on a short rest

In fact, warlock spell slots return on a short *or* long rest, not just short rests, as detailed on PHB page 107 under the **Spell Slots** section of the Warlock's Pact Magic feature:

> [...] You regain all expended slots when you finish a short or long
> rest. [...]

Answer (score 19):

### Yes, they do.

Page 107 of the PHB says, under the "Spell Slots" section:

> You regain all expended spell slots when you finish a short or long rest.